# How to use the pagination in twilio api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I can get the first page by client.call.page(args), but this will give me the object and object.nextPageUri. What should I do with this uri? I cannot find any method to go to next page in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

After loging the actual api I found getPage in the calls object.So here is how I get the next/prev pages:

`callLog = await client.calls.getPage('https://api.twilio.com' + args.input.url)`